# Xbox 360 Kinect only detected as Generic USB Hub

Tags: kinect, xbox, xbox360

I got a Kinect from Xbox 360 and I bought an adaptor to plug it to my laptop. The problem is, I already installed 1.8 SDK and developer tools but when I run Kinect Explorer it says 'kinect sensor required'. So I look the device manager I couldn't find Microsoft Kinect, there's only Generic USB Hub. I tried to use the older version, 1.7, but it makes no different. What should I do to get this Kinect works?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when connected Kinect through an external USB hub. When I plugged it directly into the PC USB port everything was OK.